# SQL iif() statement return #Error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am writing a query that joins a table of inventory and transactions. One field will tell what action can be taken depending on if the asset has a transaction (you can tell if it has an *Owner*).

I used this in that field:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Assets.ID, Assets.Item, Assets.Model, Assets.Serial,
                 Assets.Owner, Transfers.[Previous Owner], 
                 IIf([Owner]="" Or [Owner] Is Null,"Transfer","Not Available") AS [Action]
FROM Assets LEFT JOIN Transfers ON Assets.ID = Transfers.Asset;
```

The `Action` field returns `#Error` for every record. How do I get it to tell me `Transferable` is there is no owner or `Unavailable` if it has an owner?

Comment: That expression should not be generating an error, assuming the columns are properly defined.

Comment: You could change the OR statement to `IIF(NZ(Owner,"")="","Trans.....`, but as @GordonLinoff said - it should work.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172237(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: What is the data type of *Owner*? Here you treat it as a text field.

Comment: If there is also a column `Transfers.Owner`, you need to qualify the column name with the table name in the `IIf()`. Try doing that in any case.

Comment: Alternatively try this: IIF (Len([Owner] & "")=0,"Transfer","Not Available")

Answer (score 0):

I got it: the `Transfers.Asset` data type was a string and the `Assets.ID` was a number and they were conflicting.